# vue.js question : What does @import mean in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

When using bootstrap-vue, @import method is used in main.js

What does @import mean in vue.js?

And if I want to use this, do I have to use a different way than specifying an alias in "vue.config.js"?

Comment: Show more code...

Comment: Maybe you're seeing that in CSS: [`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import)